# Can't delete a symlink using ANT Script

Tags: ant, symlink, delete-file

I am trying to delete a symlink using the below line :

```
<symlink action="delete"  link="/path/of/link/symlink"/>
```

It throws an error saying:

```
Could not create tempfile in /directory/where/symlink/points
```

The /directory/where/symlink/points is supposed to be read-only. Is there a way in which I could just delete the symlink ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symlinks pointing to read-only resources may be deleted using the [`<delete>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) Ant task.

```
<target name="delete-symlink">
  <delete file="/path/of/link/symlink" followsymlinks="false"
          removenotfollowedsymlinks="true" />
</target>
```

From the `<delete>` Ant task documentation:

```
removeNotFollowedSymlinks  Whether symbolic links (not the files/directories 
                           they link to) should be removed if they haven't been 
                           followed because followSymlinks was false or the 
                           maximum number of symbolic links was too big. Since 
                           Ant 1.8.0
```